# How to convert the file path to a URL of the same file?

Tags: urls, filesystem

How do I convert file system path to URL?
I have found some general PHP solutions that can be error prone.

Is there some WordPress specific way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kind of depends on where you are in the WordPress environment.

### Plugins

If you're in a plugin, you can use [`plugins_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

```
<?php
$url = plugins_url('css/admin.css', __FILE__);
```

The above will give you the path relative to the file passed into the second argument. So if you're in the main plugin file you might get something like `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/css/admin.css`.

There's also [`plugin_dir_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) to get the URL of a directory. One fairly common pattern is to define a constant with your plugin url in the main plugin file.

```
<?php
/** plugin name: wpse216913 example */
define('WPSE216913_PLUGINURL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));

// wp_enqueue_style('example', WPSE216913_PLUGINURL.'css/admin.css');
```

### Themes

Themes, on the other hand should use [`get_template_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

`get_template_directory_uri` will return the parent theme's directory URI if there is a parent theme. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` will return the child theme's URI if there is a child theme, or the parent theme's otherwise. Read the codex for more on the differences. The [twenty fifteen theme](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/146320744f7c9ee169b67127613ef0cea882fa5c/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/functions.php#L236) has some examples of how these are used.

```
wp_enqueue_style(
  'twentyfifteen-ie',
  get_template_directory_uri().'/css/ie.css',
  array('twentyfifteen-style'),
  '20141010'
);
```

### Uploads

Use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) for uploaded images. The return value will also include the width and height of the image. This also let's you say which size you want.

Or there's [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) to retrieve the URL of the attachment that was uploaded. If used on images, this will return the URL of the original image.

If you need the URL (or path) of the upload directory so you can do something like a custom upload or otherwise, you can use [`wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) which returns an array with all the info you'll need.

```
print_r(wp_upload_dir())
/*
Array
(
    [path] => /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02
    [url] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02
    [subdir] => /2016/02
    [basedir] => /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
    [baseurl] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads
    [error] => false
)
*/
```

### Other Useful URL Functions

All of these have the same signature, `urlFunc($path, $scheme)`, and both arguments are optionall.

[`home_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) returns a path relative to the sites home page.

```
echo home_url('/example'); // http://example.com/example
```

[`site_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) returns a URL relative to where the WordPress core files are. Say you had WordPress in the directory `wp`...

```
echo site_url('/example'); // http://example.com/wp/example
```

[`admin_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) returns a URL relative to the `wp-admin` path. Useful when you need the path to `admin-ajax.php`, for instance.

```
echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');  // http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

There are a few others like `content_url` and `includes_url` which return the paths to the WP content and includes directories (or paths relative to them) respectively.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. At first I was looking for an universal solution for converting any file path to the same file url. But I think `get_template_directory_uri()` will do the job.

Answer (score 10):

**Or global**

```
function abs_path_to_url( $path = '' ) {
    $url = str_replace(
        wp_normalize_path( untrailingslashit( ABSPATH ) ),
        site_url(),
        wp_normalize_path( $path )
    );
    return esc_url_raw( $url );
}
```

Comment: What do mean by _or global_ ? It would probably help if you would an explanation to what your code does and why it helps solving the problem and how to use it.

Comment: Hey sorry for being too short. Just paste the function above in your code (example functions.php) and then you may get the url of the script from php file like this: ` $url = abs_path_to_url( dirname(__FILE__) . '/css/styles.css' );` assuming the **css** folder with **styles.css** file is in the same folder as your script.

Comment: here **global** means the above function works in both themes and plugins

Comment: As an edit to your answer, please :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution for this:

```
function convert_url_to_path( $url ) {
  return str_replace( 
      wp_get_upload_dir()['baseurl'], 
      wp_get_upload_dir()['basedir'], 
      $url
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a theme, if you want to literally convert a file system path to a URL for a given file, you would do this:

`$url = str_replace( get_stylesheet_directory(), get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), $systempath);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any wordpress path:

```
function path_to_url( $path ) {

    return get_site_url() . '/' . str_replace( ABSPATH, '', $path );

}

echo path_to_url( YOUR_PATH_HERE );
```